# Thrust Vector pointer declaration

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Is there a way to declare a Thrust Vector Pointer without actually allocating a vector? I need to use this pointer as a member variable in a class. Since I do not actually know the size of the vector beforehand, I cannot statically allocate the vector as a member variable.

Comment: vector<T> *? Is this want you want?

Comment: Nope. But it's similar to what I want, since Thrust uses host and device(GPU) vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

template <typename T>
class my_thrust_class
{
  public:
    thrust::device_ptr<T> my_dptr;
}
```

to declare a device pointer that can then be initialized to the start of whatever device_vector you want it to refer to:

```
thrust::device_vector<float> my_vec(3);
my_thrust_class<float> A;
A.my_dptr = my_vec.data();
```